# Is it possible to make Ubuntu minimize all windows before locking the screen?

Tags: lock-screen, budgie, minimize

When Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 goes screen locked either automatically after some time or by the <kbd>SuperKey</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> command, I would like to have all windows minimized at the moment of logging in again. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, however with some scripting where the script would minimize all open windows and then call the lock-screen command. That script could then be bound to the hotkey.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look for a way of doing so...

Comment: I found the command line `wmctrl -k on; gnome-screensaver-command -l` to do as I want but after assigning it a hotkey combination in the keyboard shortcuts menu, it is not working, and still don't know how to add it to the automatic (timer) screen locking D:

Comment: crtl+alt+d key minimises and restores all apps for me, try that in a keyboard shortcut then sendkeys command for control-L . Either put in a script or try && them in the shortcut definition